# Matching fight using weight as indicator

Tags: database, vb.net, if-statement, mysql-workbench

I'm building a matching system where they get match by weight with an if statement from vb and getting the registered information from the database. There would be a button in a vbform that generate the matches automatically and match them by weight and the result of the code would be shown in a datagridiew as shown like in the output code below I could put some pictures of that example but the internet is acting up I can't post it so this would be the flow, Example:

1. User X registered **Ateam(Aplayer1(90lb|50oz),Aplayer2(90lb|45oz),Aplayer3(90lb|30oz))** and **Bteam(Bplayer1(90lb|35oz),Bplayer2(90lb|55oz),Bplayer3(90lb|40oz))** and then
2. userX enters 0lb 5oz for the difference weight
3. After clicking a **generatematchbutton** they would get match randomly based on the weight diff given and would show in the datagridview just like the format in the output code below
4. And all of the teams and players are from the database

All of the registered teams would get matched with their player Example:

```
this is the output code:

Ateam|Aplayer1|90lb|50oz | Bteam|Bplayer2|90lb|55oz
Ateam|Aplayer2|90lb|45oz | Bteam|Bplayer3|90lb|40oz
Ateam|Aplayer3|90lb|30oz | Bteam|Bplayer1|90lb|35oz
```

I don't have the slightest idea how to make them into one single row thank you for your help the one with the mysql query Idk if it was possible or impossible since I'm just a beginner

[heres the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aW0u.png) 
[here it is I hope u guys can make something out if this thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeLl4.png)

Comment: Why would you post a screen shot where about 15% of it is relevant? Don't be lazy and just copy the whole desktop. Make the effort to copy only what is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM Player A, Player B
WHERE A.Id <> B.Id
AND ABS((A.Pounds * 16 + A.Ounces) - (B.Pounds * 16 + B.Ounces)) <= 5
```

I'm not sure about the correct function for calculating absolute value in MySQL but you can find that out fairly easily.

Comment: thank you for the answer but the Ateam and Bteam are rows sorry bc iddnt put picture or didnt make it clear

Comment: Just change `WHERE A.Id <> B.Id` to `WHERE A.financer_F_id <> B.financer_F_id` to make sure that players from the same team are not matched together.